# Rotate logs using different extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, logging, rotation

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/3.4.8/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) for log rotation

> When backupCount is non-zero, the system will save old log files by
>   appending the extensions ‘.1’, ‘.2’ etc., to the filename. For
>   example, with a backupCount of 5 and a base file name of app.log, you
>   would get app.log, app.log.1, app.log.2, up to app.log.5.

I would like to use different extensions - instead of **log log.1 log.2 log.3** I want to rotate into **log, log.x, log.x.x, log.x.x.x**. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the Class `RotatingFileHandler` you will find that there is a Method `doRollover` which does the rollover and naming of the logfiles:

```
def doRollover(self):
    """
    Do a rollover, as described in __init__().
    """
    if self.stream:
        self.stream.close()
        self.stream = None
    if self.backupCount > 0:
        for i in range(self.backupCount - 1, 0, -1):
            # Those are the lines, which set the filenames
            sfn = self.rotation_filename("%s.%d" % (self.baseFilename, i))
            dfn = self.rotation_filename("%s.%d" % (self.baseFilename,
                                                    i + 1))
            if os.path.exists(sfn):
                if os.path.exists(dfn):
                    os.remove(dfn)
                os.rename(sfn, dfn)
        dfn = self.rotation_filename(self.baseFilename + ".1")
        if os.path.exists(dfn):
            os.remove(dfn)
        self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
    if not self.delay:
        self.stream = self._open()
```

As you can see, there is no way of achieving what you want by using the standard `RotatingFileHandler` as there is no option to have any influence on the file naming except the base file name.

You could go by creating your own handler, that inherits from `RotatingFileHandler` and overwrite the method `doRollover`, to cover your naming scheme.